# what is the solution to this equation: $1 + 3^{x/2} = 2^x$?

Tags: exponentiation

what is the solution to this equation: $1 + 3^{x/2} = 2^x$ ?

The answer is $x = 2$. I want to know the process.

Comment: I do nkt think the tag ordinary differential equations have any relevance

Comment: Why should there be a process?  It is equivalent to solving $1^y+3^y=4^y$ where $y=2x$ and there is clearly only one solution which happens to be  $y=1$.  But there is not an obvious solution to $1^y+3^y=5^y$ (about $0.727$)

Comment: $$x=2$$ is the only real solution.

Comment: how does one solve such equation? I want to know the steps of solving such an equation. I have tried using log, I got the wrong answer.(x=0)

Answer (score 2):

First look at negative $x$. You have that $\log(1 + 3^{x/2}) >0$ whereas $\log(2^x) <0$ so there cannot be a solution.

For positive $x$, note that $3^{x/2}$ grows less than  $2^{x}$ for all positive $x$, which can simply be shown by differentiating. Further note that $1 + 3^{x/2}$ and  $2^{x}$ are strictly monotonously rising functions.

Since for $x=0$, we have that $1 + 3^{x/2} >2^{x}$, and for sufficiently large $x$, we have  that $1 + 3^{x/2} < 2^{x}$, there will be exactly one solution (with positive $x$) for $1 + 3^{x/2} = 2^{x}$. As others have already noted, you cannot directly compute this solution. However, if you have found $x=2$, you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: @MosiurRahman After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate it:
We rearrange to $$x=\log(1+\sqrt{3^x})$$

Then apply $$x_{n+1}=\log(1+\sqrt{3^{x_n}}); x_0=1$$

You can see from a calculator that $$\lim_{t\to\infty}x_t=2$$

Unfortunately, we cannot solve these.